# Django - Persistant cache

Tags: django, django-cache

Is there a way I can set a cache key indefinitely using the default django cache framework? I tried setting the timeout to 0, but that doesn't set the key at all unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Django 1.6 now accepts None for the timeout argument to specify forever.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#basic-usage

Answer (score 1):

Someone recently mentioned [Johnny Cache](http://packages.python.org/johnny-cache/index.html) in an unrelated answer. It provides a infinite caching `locmem` and `memcached` backend when a timeout of `0` is provided.

Comment: Not true. Third-party systems on top of memcached don't have any control over the fact that that system is designed to throw data away eventually when it gets full.

Comment: True that! But Johnny can still prevent invalidation due to expiration and I think that's what the OP was aiming at.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Shocked you can't do this using the standard framework though. I guess having immortal cache kind of goes against what caching is used for

Comment: I'm guessing that kind of behavior on the default `LocMem` cache backend could inadvertently blow any long-running production processes for the unaware, but using Johnny during development definitely has it's place. Plus, you just have to love this bit from the docs: "This actually doesn’t cache “forever”, just for a very long time. On 32 bit systems, it will cache for 68 years, quite a bit longer than any computer will last. On a 64 bit machine, your cache will expire about 285 billion years after the Sun goes red-giant and destroys Earth." http://goo.gl/N3vAs

Comment: last release was in [2012](https://pypi.org/project/johnny-cache/#history).